# previous trimester in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

i have following sql which gives me a report of dossiers being handled by persons the last full three months but i would like to adopt it so that i get those from the previous trimester, eg when i would run it now i should get dossiers from the months 10, 11 and 12 of 2011 and in april those from 1, 2 and 3 of 2012. Can someone make a suggestion how to handle this the easiest way. Those report are stored as sql in a database so they should be be able to run anytime.

```
select
 pers_nr "person", 
 to_char(import_dt,'YYMM') "year and month",
 count(pers_nr) "dossiers" 
from 
  rdms_3codon
where
 to_char(import_dt,'YY')*12+to_char(import_dt,'MM') > to_char(sysdate,'YY')*12+to_char(sysdate,'MM')-4
 and to_char(import_dt,'YY')*12+to_char(import_dt,'MM') < to_char(sysdate,'YY')*12+to_char(sysdate,'MM')
group by 
 pers_nr, 
 to_char(import_dt,'YYMM') 
order by
 pers_nr
```

Edit:

Here the query enhanced with the suggestion by Joachim

```
select 
 pers_nr "person",  
 to_char(import_dt,'YYMM') "year and month", 
 count(pers_nr) "dossiers"  
from  
  rdms_3codon 
where 
 trunc(import_dt) >= trunc(trunc(sysdate, 'Q') -1, 'Q')
 and trunc(import_dt) < trunc(sysdate, 'Q')-1/(24*60*60)
group by  
 pers_nr,  
 to_char(import_dt,'YYMM')  
order by 
 pers_nr
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT TRUNC(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q') -1, 'Q') AS startLastQuarter,
       TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q')-1/(24*60*60)   AS endLastQuarter,
       TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q')                AS startThisQuarter    
FROM DUAL;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94fb5/16).

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks Joachim. I have another quistion concerning the output of this query, but i'll make it a new question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  TRUNC(add_months(SYSDATE,-3*N), 'Q')  FROM DUAL;
```

Remplace N por el numero de trimestre que quiere ir atras.

Comment: The comment is not in English... Could you fix that?